# Laravel 7- Pass database value or a value stored in a variable, to Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel

I am trying to obtain value from database and pass it to blade. If there is no value in database, a random number is generated and passed from the controller. However, I am unable to fetch the value even if it exists. I am getting **1** for every value available in database

Here are my codes

**Controller**

```
public function new_user2(Request $request){
  if(!Auth::check()){
    $reference = $request->refno;
    if((is_null($reference))){

            $ref1   =  mt_rand(10,1000);
            $ref2   =  mt_rand();
            $reference    =  $ref1."-".$ref2;  
          
   } else{
           $tuser = DB::table('temp_users')->where('referenceno',$reference)->first();
          
           if(is_null($tuser)){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error',"Invalid Reference No. Please enter a valid one");
            }else{
              // return view('multipage1',compact('tuser'));
                return view('multipage1',compact('tuser'));
            }
        }

return view('multipage1')->with('ref',$reference);
}else{
  Auth::login();
    }

}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="body1">
    <div class="container container2">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <h1 class="text-white text-center display-2">Step 1</h1>
          <div class="login-form">
            <form id="newuser2_step1" action="{{url('mpage2')}}" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                @csrf
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="RefNo">Reference Number: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="refno" name="refno" value="{{$tuser->referenceno or $ref}}" readonly><br>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <!-- Alert Message -->
                  <div class="alert alert-danger " role="alert" id="alerts">
                       <strong id="emailtaken"></strong>
                 </div>

                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{$tuser->temp_email or ''}}">
                <div class="error text-danger" ></div> 
              </div>
              
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn2 btn-primary" id="mstep1">Get Started</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Database table**

Data exists in **referenceno** and **temp_email** columns
[image]

**Output in Browser**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator), the Laravel `or` operator that you used, is discontinued. So, use  [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) instead.

`value="{{$tuser->referenceno ?? $ref}}"`

Similarly, replace the email value with similar coede

Answer (score 1):

You have change this type of statements `{{$tuser->referenceno or $ref}}`

It is basically checking true/false that why you are getting 1.

Do something like this `{{ isset($tuser->referenceno) ? $tuser->referenceno : $ref}}`